# how to set ipython on a virtualenv?

Tags: ipython, elpy, virtualenv

I'm using elpy for my python coding. I wanted to try ipython because of the nice built in profilers. So what I've done is to install ipython within my virtualenv. It works correctly. I then added the following line to my `init.el`

```
(elpy-use-ipython)
```

However after restarting emacs I get the error that command iypthon is not found. Is it possible to set ipython on a virtualenv basis? Or how can I fix the issue. I'm running linux debian 9.3 stretch

Comment: I don't use elpy, but looking at the source it says `elpy-use-ipython` is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the docstring for the deprecated `elpy-use-ipython`, it points to https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#interpreter-setup that recommends the following setup for ipython:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```

If it still fails, you could try using full path to your ipython executable.

Answer (score 0):

recomme

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "jupyter"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "console --simple-prompt"
      python-shell-prompt-detect-failure-warning nil)
(add-to-list 'python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters
             "jupyter")
```

Comment: What does "recomme" mean?  Please clarify and explain what those Elisp chunks are supposed to do.